# How to write and package a C++ library which uses templates

Tags: c++, compilation, packaging

Since templates have to be defined/impemented in the header file, how do we go about packaging such a library given that we don't want to share the source code ?

Comment: You have no choice, you have to share the source code.

Comment: The template code enforces type safety, but calls implementation code that uses generic constructs, like `vector<char>`. As a straightforward example, you can imagine a `sort` interface using templates, but the template code ends up calling C's `qsort`.

Comment: Are you willing to limit the allowed parameters for a template? If not, you have to share (at least part of) the source code. Using the standard library as an example, if you define a class `A` and use `std::vector<A>`, the code for `std::vector<A>` does not exist until your code is compiled -- that code is not directly in the library. On the other hand, one could limit vectors to, say, `std::vector<int>` and `std::vector<long>` and distribute that as a binary release. So... how flexible does your library need to be?

Comment: Thanks @JaMiT. If impossible without limiting, say I can limit the types. Sorry, but how is that done ? Does that involve template specialization ?

Comment: Thanks @jxh. would you have any reference for the approach you mentioned. Given the template code is calling C's qsort, do we need to cast/specialize the input argument before passing it to qsort ?

Comment: Yes, it involves template specialisation.  You can forward declare a template (without a body) in your header file and then put a specialisation for each set of types you want to support in your compiled code.  Then, if you (or a user of your library) try to instantiate the template with a set of types for which there is no specialisation, you will get a linker error.  But I don't think this would be a good solution - the whole power of templates is that they can be instantiated with a more-or-less ad-hoc set of types without having to write separate code for each.

Comment: Yes. that makes sense. If I have to forward declare for each type, there is no reason to get templates involved. At least that's what my naive understanding is. 

I am also wondering if with the introduction of concepts in c++20, will we be able to have forward declaration (using concepts) in header and implementation in cpp file. Any clue ?

Comment: Not forward declare for each type (although you do have to do that) -  specialise (i.e provide a separate implementation for each type).  There's a difference, do a bit of googling on template specialization to learn more.  But it would be an abuse of template specialisation to use it in this way; don't.

Comment: oh yeah. sorry about that bad phrase. i understand difference between specialization and forward declaration. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: It is as Yakk explained in his answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can forward declare template specializations and export them from your dll, but only for a specific set of types.

One alternative is to leverage type erasure.  Here, your public headers are templated, but they convert into non template code.

For example, you could write a library that does image processing on extremely flexible formats.  The user provides the bit depth and meaning and order of the channels (additive, linear, multiple transparencies, etc).

You store the channel information and create a flat buffer of bytes,
and inside the library build have enough stufd to handle all of the combinations without "crossing the ABI" with templates.

This can get ridiculously extreme.  For example, Skia has shaders that at runtime you can provide SkSL strings that it cross compiles to the GPU or CPU based image processing you choose, which then produces executable code which it run, optimized, on the buffers.  Skia doesn't allow custom buffer layouts, but nothing fundamentally blocks it.

All of this is advanced and obscure.  The simplest template libraries are just header only, with maybe a kernel of non template code.